# About Custom View Margin

Tags: android, view, margin

MyView extends View, and draw a circle in onDraw().However it is often clipped if I set margin to its parent layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    ... >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RAM" />

        <my.ui.ClockView2
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/ram_cv"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

I tried to calculate the margin, but only got the padding:

```
    _availableWidth = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
    _availableHeight = getHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
```

Is there any way to avoid this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're doing this from within your view, so try this:

```
        MarginLayoutParams lp = (MarginLayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
        int[] mymargin = {
                lp.leftMargin,
                lp.rightMargin,
                lp.topMargin,
                lp.bottomMargin,
        };
```